# Adding Legal Notice Links To The Bottom Of Template

Tags: html, css

Like many websites, I'm looking to put legal notices at the bottom of every page.  I know how to link, but don't know how to embed the following right above the copyright without a huge gap:

Home | Contact | Disclaimer | Privacy Policy | Terms & Conditions

Can someone please advise?  I'd like to use CSS for this instead of the BR code.  Thanks.

CSS:

```
#footer {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    width: 850px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer .social {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
}

#footer .social ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#footer .social li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#footer .social img {
    border: 0px;
}

#footer .copyright {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="copyright">
    Copyright &copy; 2011 Ricky Wai Kit Tsang.  All rights reserved.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a huge gap, you can remove or reduce the `margin` and `line-height` in your `.copyright` div

```
.copyright {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 32px;   //reduce or remove
    margin-top: 10px;    //reduce or remove
}
```

Comment: Just place the link list in a `div` or a `p`.